# Selenium Webdriver + Python. Целесообразность использования time.sleep()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Я недавно стала заниматься автоматизацией (Selenium Webdriver + Python), и не уверена насколько правильно использовать `time.sleep()` в следующей ситуации:

На странице есть группы фильтров, некоторые из них свернуты, и прежде чем начать с ними работать, необходимо все группы развернуть. Для этого я прохожусь по всем свернутым элементам.

При этом у меня возникает эксепшен:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (184, 250). Other element would receive the click: <div class="icon-holder" data-bind="visible: collapsible()">...</div>
```

Я добавила `time.sleep(1)` после каждого `.click()`, тогда все отрабатывает. Но не уверена, насколько это правильное решение в данном случае. Буду благодарна за помощь.

```
element_list = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)
    for element in element_list:
        if element.is_displayed():
        element.click()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Python Selenium (waiting for frame, element lookups)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9823272/4279)

Comment: Ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823272/python-selenium-waiting-for-frame-element-lookups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаток Selenium, и не знаю, как такие случаи канонично обрабатываются средствами Selenium.

В принципе time.sleep - вполне себе вариант. Но если таких элементов у вас на странице будет 100 - вы будете получать задержку в почти 2 минуты. А если вы выставите слишком маленькую паузу - то будет вылетать исключение когда не надо.

Я бы использовал в этом месте довольно популярный прием - повторял вызов функции N раз если вылетает какое-нибудь исключение с периодичностью в T.

Вот пример как можно преобразовать вашу функция при помощи библиотеки [invl/retry](https://github.com/invl/retry)

```
from retry import retry
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
...
@retry(WebDriverException, tries=3, delay=0.3)
def click_element(element):
    if element.is_displayed():
        element.click()

element_list = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)
    for element in element_list:
        click_element(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

В Selenium есть более правильное ожидание - WebDriverWait, в гугл много примеров, довольно мощный инструмент.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать time.sleep() худший вариант, который можно придумать, т.к. время прохождение тестов очень сильно увеличивается.
Рекомендуется все делать через явные\неявные ожидания http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html
Например так:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
element_list = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)
    for element in element_list:
        wait.until(visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector_2)))
        element.click()
```

Comment: а как вы думаете, что делает внутри себя WebDriverWait =)? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py#L77

Comment: @rusnasonov существенное отличие в наличии условия и величине индивидуальной паузы (не 5 секунд)

Comment: @jfs если честно, не совсем понял ваш довод. Если использовать подход с retry, то можно добиться абсолютно такого-же поведения, как и WebDriverWait.until (по сути там и реализовано поведение retry). Пользователь Tox написал что "Использовать time.sleep() худший вариант, который можно придумать". А я утверждаю что не худший, так как иначе попросту никак). Вопрос в том КАК будет использован time.sleep - однократно, или с повторением.

Comment: @rusnasonov есть разница между `self._poll` и `self._timeout` и не нужно велосипед изобретать (API известное людям, которое уже на нескольких языках имеет реализации, которое может быть оптимизировано и другую реализацию  иметь в зависимости от возможностей driver)

Comment: @jfs да, я понимаю что есть разница и зачем это все надо. Да, в общем случае велосипеды делать не стоит. Но и кактусы жевать тоже не нужно, и оверинжиниринг делать тоже не нужно. Есть стандартное средство - пользуйся. А если оно тебя не устраивает - не делает то, что нужно, или слишком сложное, или не удобное, сделай своё.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте Exeption возможно там AJAX  создает проблемы

```
def waitElementPresentByCss (timeout, numberAttempts, elementCss):
    if numberAttempts!=0:
        time.sleep(timeout)
        print "Debug: attempt number " + str(numberAttempts)
    else: return

    print elementCss
    try:
        elm = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(elementCss)
        if elm.is_displayed()!=True:
            waitElementPresentByCss(timeout, numberAttempts-1, elementCss)
        print "Debug: Try block"
    except:
        waitElementPresentByCss(timeout, numberAttempts - 1, elementCss)
        print "Debug: except block"


waitElementPresentByCss (3, 3, '#LearnMore[href*="/some-css"]')
```

Comment: Последнея строчка, что с ней?